# Convert Cartesian function to polar function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

A problem on my math homework is $x = -4$ convert to a polar function. What are the steps, the examples in my book are only for $y=x$ functions.

Comment: (x,y) -> (radius,angle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert Cartesian to polar, remember that we use $x= r\cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$. Since we know $x=-4$, just replace $x$ by $-4$ to get $\color{red}{r\cos\theta = -4}$

Comment: Ok so r = -4secθ. Thank you I didn't think of that